# Display a real time clock (using server time) on aspx page

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, datetime

Right now I am displaying a clock (Hour: Minute + Date) on the aspx page using updatepanel and timer, it causes server side post back every 30 seconds. I don't like this solution. I would like to have a JavaScript clock that starts out with a base value from the server. Could anybody come up with a better alternative than the code below?

```
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanelClock" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
             <asp:Label ID="lblTime2" runat="server"></asp:Label>
         </ContentTemplate>
         <Triggers>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Timer2" EventName="Tick" />
         </Triggers>
   </asp:UpdatePanel>

    <asp:Timer ID="Timer2" runat="server" Interval="30000" OnTick="Timer2_Tick"></asp:Timer>
```

Code behind

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
      {
         lblTime2.Text = DateTimeOffset.Now.ToString("hh:mm tt") + " - " + DateTimeOffset.Now.ToString("dddd, MMMM dd");
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

In my own library I created the function `getCurrentTime`. It's a versatile getter and converter of date and time. This function can create dates from timestamps in microseconds. It allows you to create clocks, calendars, countdown timer, etc.

```
months = "Jan:31;Feb:28;Mar:31;Apr:30;May:31;Jun:30;Jul:31;Aug:31;Sep:30;Oct:31;Nov:30;Dec:31";
function getCurrentTime(unixTimeStamp)
{
    if (unixTimeStamp)
    {
        this.dateObject = new Date(unixTimeStamp);
    }
    else
    {
        this.dateObject = new Date();
    }
    // Time
    this.dateObject.h = this.dateObject.getHours();
    this.dateObject.m = this.dateObject.getMinutes();
    if (this.dateObject.m < 10)
    {this.dateObject.m = "0" + this.dateObject.m;}
    this.dateObject.s = this.dateObject.getSeconds();
    if (this.dateObject.s < 10)
    {this.dateObject.s = "0" + this.dateObject.s;}

    //Date
    this.dateObject.y = parseInt(this.dateObject.getFullYear());
    this.dateObject.mo = this.dateObject.getMonth()+1;
    if (this.dateObject.mo < 10)
    {this.dateObject.mo = "0" + this.dateObject.mo;}
    this.dateObject.d = this.dateObject.getDate();
    if (this.dateObject.d < 10)
    {this.dateObject.d = "0" + this.dateObject.d;}
    this.today = this.dateObject.d + "/" + this.dateObject.mo + "/" + this.dateObject.y;
    this.now = this.dateObject.d + "/" + this.dateObject.mo + "/" + this.dateObject.y + " " + this.dateObject.h + ":" + this.dateObject.m + ":" + this.dateObject.s;
    this.dateStamp = Date.parse(this.dateObject.mo+"/"+this.dateObject.d+"/"+this.dateObject.y);

    //these are the objects returned by getCurrentTime() next to hour, minutes, seconds, year, month and date.
    this.dateObject.fullDate = this.dateObject.d + " " + months.split(/;/)[this.dateObject.mo-1].split(/:/)[0] + " " + this.dateObject.y;
    this.dateObject.timeZoneOffset = dateObject.getTimezoneOffset(); //in minutes.
    this.dateObject.today = this.today;
    this.dateObject.now = this.now;
    this.dateObject.dateStamp = this.dateStamp;

    return this.dateObject;
}

    timeStamp = <%= ConvertToTimestamp(DateTime.UtcNow).ToString() %>
    setInterval(clock, 1000);

    function clock()
    {   
        timeStamp += 1000;
        var timeObj = getCurrentTime(timeStamp);
        var timeString = timeObj.h + ":" + timeObj.m + ":" + timeObj.s;
        console.log(timeString);
    }
```

This function without `unixTimeStamp` gets the clients time settings, but if you load a date var into it with aspx `<%= ConvertToTimestamp(DateTime.UtcNow).ToString() %>` it will update from the time stamp it got. How to retrieve time stamp:

```
public double ConvertToTimestamp(DateTime value)
{
    //create Timespan by subtracting the value provided from
    //the Unix Epoch
    TimeSpan span = (value - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0).ToLocalTime());

    //return the total milliseconds (which is a UNIX timestamp * 1000)
    return (long)span.TotalMilliseconds;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3Lp4mwpn/ : example

Please note that `getCurrentTime` is returning an object with more possibilities than showing time. It can provide you with multiple date formats.

Comment: does this display server time or client time? I want it to display server time.

Comment: Both. To show server time you need to get the server time and convert it to a `timestamp` in `milliseconds` and insert that into the `getCurrentTime` function.

Comment: @RonaldinhoLearnCoding, So replace `timeStamp = 1420671199000;` with `timestamp = <%= timestamp %>` where the latter is the retrieved server time as unix time stamp in milliseconds.

Comment: what is `timestamp` in <%= timestamp %>? I tried `timeStamp = <%= DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmssfff") %>;` but it didn't work, shows nothing

Comment: @RonaldinhoLearnCoding I've updated the answer with C# code to retrieve a correct time stamp. This should give you a javascript based clock with server time. Enjoy.

Comment: for some reason I forgot I asked this question here, I skipped this and moved on with my project, almost get it done, I probably come back and add this to my wen app asap, I really appreciate your help Mouser, will let you know after I try this.